# matlab Conversion to double from cell is not possible error message

Tags: matlab, plot, message

here is my code:

```
%% Load and plot precipitation data

%Read the salinity data file
fid = fopen('Everglades Precip USHDCN.csv');

%Read the salinity data file
everglades_ushcn_data = textscan(fid, '%f %*f %f %*s %f f', 'HeaderLines',2, 'Delimiter', ',');

%Close the data file
fclose(fid);

%Precip data is in the 2nd column
everglades_precip_data = everglades_ushcn_data(:, 4);

%Convert everything to a matrix
matrix_data = cell2mat(everglades_ushcn_data);

%Convert a date vector to a date number
datenums = datenum(matrix_data(:, 3:-1:1));

%Select dates
everglades_precip_year = everglades_ushcn_data{3};


%Plot surface precip data
figure
plot(datenums,everglades_precip_data)

%Convert the x axis to label date
datetick(gca)

xlabel ('Date', 'Fontsize', 14)
ylabel('Precipitation', 'Fontsize', 14)
title('Everglades Precipitation', 'Fontsize', 16)
```

The error message I get says:

Error using plot
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in Evergladesprecipushdcn (line 28)
plot(datenums,everglades_precip_data)

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 6):

You can probably fix it with this:

```
plot(datenums,[everglades_precip_data{:}]);
```

or this:

```
plot(datenums,cell2mat(everglades_precip_data));
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH! I have been doing this for 2 days the first line worked! thank you!